# Casperjs can't open website

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

Trying to get into https://www.germaniasport.hr/hr/kladjenje/ponuda using casperjs 1.1.4 phantomjs 1.9.8, but can't find what protection is using this website. Tried with ip adress, tried casperjs --ssl-protocol=tlsv1, casperjs --ssl-protocol=any - but no results.

```
var casper = require('casper').create(
{
 pageSettings:
{
    loadImages:  false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'
},
verbose: false,
logLevel: "debug",
viewportSize : { width: 1920, height: 1080 }
});
 casper.start('https://91.213.84.25/hr/kladjenje/ponuda', function() {
this.wait(5000);
this.capture("sh.jpg");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `casper.run();`at the end of your code, so your code never actually runs...

Comment: I have that, but I didn't wrote that here .
     casper.run(function()
   {
    casper.exit();
   });